Evaluate $\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-t/n)^n$.
I am a physicist and I have an infinite sum that came up while doing a Random Matrix Theory calculation:
$$
\mbox{Evaluate}\quad\operatorname{f}\left(t\right) =
\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}
\left(-\,{t \over n}\right)^{n}
$$
I would like a closed-form expression that is either exact or asymptotically equivalent as $t\to \infty$.

I've evaluated it numerically and it seems to be negative, and convergent as $t \to \infty$.
I've tried using the residue theorem as in sum of an alternating series.

I got stuck because the sum is not symmetric
under $n \to -n$.


As $t\to\infty$, the absolute value of the terms peaks around $n \approx t$, which suggests using Laplace's Method, but the calculation is complicated by the alternating sign.
To deal with the alternating sign, I tried grouping terms in odd-even pairs, as they mostly cancel, but in the end, I got stuck.
I used Stirling's Approximation to get
$$
\operatorname{f}\left(t\right) \sim \sum_{n = 1} \,\sqrt{\,{2\pi n}\,}\,\frac{(-t/e)^n}{n!}, \quad t\to \infty $$
which is almost the series expansion for an exponential.
I tried regrouping terms using an Euler Transformation.


I believe a closed form doesn't exist, especially considering the fact there's no known closed form for even the $t=1$ case.

For $t=1$ this is one instance of Sophomore's dream, i.e.
$$
f(1) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \left(\frac{-1}{n}\right)^n  = - \int_0^1 x^{x}\,dx \simeq - 0.7834305107
$$
so yes, it converges, but the limit is not a functional value.
For other $t$, one can define (see here) a "Sophomore's dream function"
$$
S(\alpha, x) = \int_0^x q^{\alpha q} \,dq
$$
and as the cited paper further states (scroll down),
$$
S(\alpha, 1) = - \frac{1}{\alpha} \sum_{n=1}^\infty \left(\frac{-\alpha}{n}\right)^n 
$$
So putting the pieces together and changing to your notation, apparently your "solution" is
$$
f(t) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \left(\frac{-t}{n}\right)^n = -t S(t,1) = -t \int_0^1 x^{t x} \,dx
$$
which appears to converge for fixed $t$. If  you continue reading the cited paper, there are approximations and graphs with numerical values.

Edit: The answer you desire is  $\lim_{t \to \infty} f(t) = - \lim_{t \to \infty} t \int_0^1 x^{t x} \,dx \color{red}{= - 1}$.  It took a little while to find it since it is somewhat historic in MSE, but here you go with two proofs:
By Sangchul Lee and by user26872, all in 2013.

This reference is relevant, thanks. But I'm struggling to see if there's a result in that paper that will give me the $t \to \infty$ asymptotics of $f(t)$. Eq 9:3 does not seem to be helpful. I do not understand why in 6:4 the author says that Sphd(\alpha,1) is negligible, given that $x=1$ seems to be a special case of the asymptotic expansion if $\alpha \gg 1$.

Your sum could be rewritten as a power series
$$f(t) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{n^n}t^n= \sum_{n=1}^\infty a_nt^n$$
using the root test we have
$$C = \limsup_{n\to \infty} \sqrt[n]{|a_n|} = 0$$
we can conclude that the radius of convergence for the power series is $r= \infty$, good news!
We can notice also that
$$ 0 \leq |a_n| \leq \frac{1}{n!}$$
so we have that
$$\begin{align*}|f(t)| &= \bigg| \sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n t^n\bigg| \\
&\leq \sum_{n=1}^\infty |a_n |t^n \leq  \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n!}t^n\\
&= e^t -1
\end{align*} $$
Here start a flow of thoughts... since we started with $(-t)^n$ this led me to think that maybe the sum of $f(t)$ is bounded by $e^{-t}-1 $ and for $t\to \infty \ f(t) \leq -1$. At the moment I'm not able to formalize this process rigorously, more than an answer is sharing some thoughts about this problem.
Maybe finding a lower bound could led to a complete solution since in another answer to this post is cited that the solution for $\lim_{t\to \infty}f(t) = -1$.

My hope is to have shared another point of view that does not sound to silly!
